# What was the spiritual significance of the blood being used as a means of atonement, dedication, and purification?

Tags: kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, ark-aron-kodesh, blood, kaparah-atonement

Blood played a significant role within Israelite Culture ceremoniously and ritualistically.  For example (including but not limited to) for [confirmation of a covenant](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.24.8), as part of the [dedication of the *kohanim*](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.29.20), as part of the [priestly service on Yom Kippur](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.16.14), and as part of the [purification of the *metzora*](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.14.14).

What was the spiritual significance of the blood being used as a means of atonement, dedication, and purification?  Was there an overall connection of the usage of blood ceremoniously or was there a different reason for its usage on a case by case basis?  Also was this a cultural practice amongst the nations that surrounded ancient Israel (not just in proximity but during the time period) as a means of reconciliation with their deities? Commentaries, Articles, Scriptural Passages, etc. Todah Rabbah.

Comment: You don't need to go very far afield: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.17.11?lang=he&aliyot=0. Specifically, [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi%20on%20Leviticus%2017:11:1).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123507/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-).